# JNDI: How to monitor Directory server for updates

Tags: jndi

I want to get notify whenever there is a CRUD operation on directory server. Can some body suggest me, is there any API, to monitor a directory for updates. My directory server is located in some other machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directory Servers record the changes in their Change Log if it is enabled. For example in Oracle Internet Directory cn=changelog is located directly under Root DSE. You can use JNDI APIs to read changes recorded in change log.

Comment: Thanks for the info. you mean there is no call back mechanism provided by JNDI, when there is a change in Active directory?

Comment: There are event listeners in JNDI, but it is up to the DS to send the notifications. This link discusses how to get updates from AD using JNDI :https://community.oracle.com/thread/1157474?start=0&tstart=0